# Identify invalid dates in pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we had the following dataframe-

How can I create the fourth column 'Invalid dates' as specified below using the first three columns in the dataframe?

```
  Name       Date1       Date2  Invalid dates
0    A  01-02-2022  03-04-2000           None
1    B          23  12-12-2012          Date1
2    C  18-04-1993         abc          Date2
3    D          45         qcf   Date1, Date2
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the Dates column with [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) (or any other method, including a manual list), compute a Series of invalid dates by converting [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and sub-selecting the NaN values (i.e. invalid dates) with [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html),then [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to the original DataFrame:

```
s = (df
     .filter(like='Date') # keep only "Date" columns
      # convert to datetime, NaT will be invalid dates
     .apply(lambda s: pd.to_datetime(s, format='%d-%m-%Y', errors='coerce'))
     .isna()
     # reshape to long format (Series)
     .stack()
    )

out = (df
       .join(s[s].reset_index(level=1)    # keep only invalid dates
            .groupby(level=0)['level_1']  # for all initial indices
            .agg(','.join)                # join the column names
            .rename('Invalid Dates')
           )
       )
```

alternative with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.malt.html) to reshape the DataFrame:

```
cols = df.filter(like='Date').columns

out = df.merge(
    df.melt(id_vars='Name', value_vars=cols, var_name='Invalid Dates')
      .assign(value=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d['value'], format='%d-%m-%Y',
                                             errors='coerce'))
      .loc[lambda d: d['value'].isna()]
      .groupby('Name')['Invalid Dates'].agg(','.join),
    left_on='Name', right_index=True, how='left'
)
```

output:

```
  Name       Date1       Date2 Invalid Dates
0    A  01-02-2022  03-04-2000           NaN
1    B          23  12-12-2012         Date1
2    C  18-04-1993         abc         Date2
3    D          45         qcf   Date1,Date2
```

Comment: @HarishaG you're welcome, did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for filter columns with substring `Date`, then convert to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) all columns of `df1` with `errors='coerce'` for missing values if no match, so possible test them by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and by [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) extract columnsnames separated by `,`:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='Date')
df['Invalid dates']=((df1.apply(lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x,format='%d-%m-%Y',errors='coerce'))
                        .isna() & df1.notna())
                        .dot(df1.columns + ',')
                        .str[:-1]
                        .replace('', np.nan))

print (df)
  Name       Date1       Date2 Invalid dates
0    A  01-02-2022  03-04-2000           NaN
1    B          23  12-12-2012         Date1
2    C  18-04-1993         abc         Date2
3    D          45         qcf   Date1,Date2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If one of the date entries is NaN, it is still getting captured as an invalid date. How do i go about it?

Comment: @HarishaG - Can you test edited answer? added `& df1.notna()`

Comment: It's working. Many thanks for your help! I really appreciate it.